# Young adult or middle grade fantasy book from the 90s-2000s about a girl in a town or village who thinks she doesn't have magic

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, magic

I'm looking for a young adult or middle grade fantasy book from the 90s-2000s.

A girl is in a town or village and she thinks she doesn't have magic. An eccentric or someone unexpected tells her she does and takes her on to teach her how to use her powers. She is some kind of special power user.

Not much to go on but I will know it when I see it!!